# JEXL: How to customize property accessors

Tags: java, jexl

I've got data objects, which you could think of as a "simplified map". There are methods `get(String)`, and `put(String,Object)`, but that's basically it.

Now, I'd like to use JEXL to evaluate complex expressions on my data objects. I can do so by creating a custom JexlContext, and that works for expressions like *"foo"*, or `foo != null`. However, as soon as I attempt to use an expression like *"foo.bar"*, Jexl fails with an error message "unsolvable property".
Obviously, Jexl uses my custom JexlContext to evaluate *"foo"*, but can't evaluate *"bar"* on the foo object.
My impression is, that I've got to use a custom PropertyResolver. I can implement that, but I can't figure out. how to bring that into the game, as the JexlUberspect doesn't contain a method like `setResolvers`, or `addResolver`.

Comment: Is there a reference of the code you can share ?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447971

Comment: This question should not be marked duplicate. They are different topics , but both solved with JexlArithmetic. Just because both topics use JexlArithmetic as solution does not mean they are duplicate.

Comment: If any asker already knew Jexl property is part of JexlArithmetic, then they would not have needed to ask the question. Voted to reopen question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the duplicate question, I guess you can do:

```
public class ExtendedJexlArithmetic extends JexlArithmetic
{
    public Object propertyGet(YourCustomClass left, YourCustomClass right)
    {
       // ...
    }
}

JexlEngine jexlEngine=new JexlBuilder().arithmetic(new ExtendedJexlArithmetic (true)).create();
// or
JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine(null, new ExtendedJexlArithmetic(), null, null);
```

From the documentation at: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jexl3/package-summary.html

> You can also add methods to overload property getters and setters operators behaviors. Public methods of the JexlArithmetic instance named propertyGet/propertySet/arrayGet/arraySet are potential overrides that will be called when appropriate. The following table is an overview of the relation between a syntactic form and the method to call where V is the property value class, O the object class and P the property identifier class (usually String or Integer).
>
> ```
> Expression                   Method Template
> foo.property              public V propertyGet(O obj, P property);
>
> foo.property = value      public V propertySet(O obj, P property, V value);
>
> foo[property]             public V arrayGet(O obj, P property, V value);
>
> foo[property] = value     public V arraySet(O obj, P property, V value);
> ```